# Как найти в этом массиве все объект со значением

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var obj = [
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 14.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 14.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 2.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
    ];
</script>
```

Есть такой массив. Как найти в этом массиве все объект со значением "date: 14.2". Не могу понять как использовать indexOF если вообще можно использовать его тут. Если нет то как использовать find()

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = [
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 14.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 14.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
        {
            text: 'первая задача',
            done: false || true,
            date: 2.2,
            checkedDone: false
        },
    ];
    
var result = obj.filter(item => item.date == 14.2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну если надо с использованием indexOf то так

```
let joke = obj.map(v => v.date).filter((v, i, arr) => {
  return arr.indexOf(v) === i && v === 14.2 ? v : null
}).filter(v => v);
```